Caneta Wacon 21UX
Good afternoon,
My pen loses contact if I move away from the screen, and it doesn't come back in Krita. I have to press the super key to simulate switching programs to get it back. I also noticed that there are two grip pens in the settings after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04. enter image description hereenter image description here
System Details Report
Report Details
Created Date: 2024-09-20 22:12:31
##Device Information:
Device Model: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3060
Memory: 8.0 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-8100T × 4
Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
Disk Capacity: 500.1 GB
##Software Information:
Firmware Version: 1.29.0
OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04. 1 LTS
OS Build: (null)
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 46
Window Manager: Wayland
Kernel Version: Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

The language here at Ask Ubuntu is English. Please translate your question to English.
